# Add date & time format to client side form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, ejs, bootstrap-5

I'm using bootstrap5 and ejs create a form where the second input should be a "start date." I'm new-ish to bootstrap and can't find anything in the docs that lets me place a date-picker in the form. Here's my form so far:

```
<% layout('layouts/boilerplate') %> 
<div class="row">
    <h1 class="text-center">Create Event</h1>
    <div class="col-6 offset-3">
        <form action="/events/new" method="POST" novalidate class="validated-form">
            <div class="mb-3">
                <label class="form-label" for="event_name">Event name</label>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="event[event_name]" name="event[event_name]" required autofocus>
                <div class="valid-feedback">
                    Looks good!
                </div>
            <div class="mb-3">
                <button class="btn btn-success">Create Event</button>
            </div>
            <a href="/events">Event</a>
        </form>        
    </div>
</div>
```

My model is waiting for 'event_start' right below 'event_name' but I don't know how to configure the form to ensure users enter in the correct format.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const eventSchema = new Schema({
  event_name: String,
  event_start: {
    type: Date,
    required: [true, 'Date & time of event start required']
    },
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Event', eventSchema);
```

How do I add a section to my form right below the 'event_name' field that would force the user to enter date/time in line with what the model is expecting?

Comment: Did you look for a bootstrap datepicker package?

Comment: Yes, I downloaded bootstrap-datepicker@1.9.0 but am struggling with the docs